# regular expression to satisfy form of string like X7O9 - 0qiLA0 with specific set of rules

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out a regular expression that satisfies a string like `X7O9 - 0qiL0` where number of characters between `-` separator is 3 to 5 on each side.

Furthermore have additional rules like:

> 1) have 1 to 2 numbers on left hand side
>   2) have 0 - 2 lowercase letters on right hand side
>   3) have 1 or more uppercase letters on left hand side

if possible account for their random positions within a string i.e. for rule no.3 uppercase letter can be first, second, third etc.. as long as it is on the left hand side it will be dine.

So far I figured out how to achieve my base rule of 3 - 5 characters on each side of the separator: `(\w{3,5}) - (\w{3,5})`

Comment: What is the purpose of the regex? Are you just looking for things that match, or do you actually want to parse values from it?

Comment: It might be easier just to do `(\w{3,5}) - (\w{3,5})` and then pull each capture group and send them to individual verification functions, i.e. `hasLowercase(2, word)` or `hasUppercase(1, word)`

Comment: @RPGillespie I'm using a js library that generates random string that will satisfy given regex, hence I want to generate one from regex I'm trying to figure out above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex, it would be:

```
^(?=\D*\d\D*\d?\D* -)(?=.*[A-Z].* -).{3,5} - (?=[^a-z]*[a-z]?[^a-z]*[a-z]?[^a-z]*).{3,5}$
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/wJ2nU6/2)